# How to add copyright to Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, copyright-display

The title says everything. If I want to add copyright comment in code files in Eclipse Helios, how can I do it? Manually copy-paste or is there any other way?

Comment: *"copy-pest"* --- I'll have to remember that one :-)

Comment: @Stephen C thanks for reply. So no other way? Any plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to preferences Java/CodeStyle/Code Templates

then expand Code, and New Java Files, edit that, and put in whatever text you want. Now whenever you create a class, that will be automatically injected.

Answer (score 4):

Was looking into doing this for my project and found this plugin quite useful

http://www.wdev91.com/?p=cpw_ug

Answer (score 2):

You can also install the Eclipse Releng tools (from the eclipse 3.6 update site included in Helios).  I can add copyright headers to existing files and update existing copyright headers to include the current year.

See http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/org.eclipse.releng.tools.feature.group for more information.

Comment: Tool doesn't work for me and is severely bugged, only adding IBM copyright, ignoring all other copyright inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is similar for C++ code in Eclipse CDT:
Window:Preferences:C/C++:Code Style:Code Templates:Comments:Files:Edit

The resulting dialog has a button for inserting variables such as time, date, year, file name, etc.